# custom fields hidden when using Advanced custom field wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Before using Advanced Custom fields, I can show custom fields from `screen options` for the page

[image]

After installing Advanced Custom Fields,  custom fields hidden from `screen options`.

After I deactivate Advanced custom fields, it appear again.

can I show custom fields after installing Advanced custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default The Advance Custom field removes the default custom field from WordPress. because it is already providing you with custom fields to be added.
But somehow if you really need to use the default customer field. then you can create your own meta boxes for that.
here is a sample example.

```
function add_custom_fields_to_pages() {
  add_meta_box('custom_fields', 'Custom Fields', 'custom_fields_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}

function custom_fields_meta_box() {
  global $post;
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
 
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>';
  echo '<input type="text" name="custom_field" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field', true).'" />';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

You can change the name of it because it is only a new meta box.

here is another example: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: Are you test this solution? - it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you add this in your function file?

Comment: Yes, I added the function to functions.php file

Comment: print_r the $values, what you get when initializing the code.

Comment: also you can change the priority of add_filter I am using 10, you can use 20 to be init.

Comment: I change the priority but nothing change, I think There is a confuse between Advanced custom fields and pure custom fields in Wordpress. 
because when I deactivate Advanced custom fields, the pure custom fields appear without any problem.

Comment: Are you use Advanced Custom fields with pure custom fields in Wordpress before?

Comment: Yes, I am a WordPress developer, and I used the Advance custom field in our WordPress, but BTW, if you are using ACF then why do you need to use default custom fields?

Comment: @shbham I can use Advanced Custom fields But why ACF conflict with pure custom fields in WordPress? -  special thanks for you and your efforts.

Comment: I followed you in `linkedin` you can send to me a connection request and glad to know you.